# How to copy value from one list to another list having different objects

Tags: java

I have MaterailInfo and StyleInfo, I want to set styleDescription based on StyleNumber matching with materialNumber. I am using 2 for loops, is there any alternative solution?

**MaterailInfo:**

```
class MaterailInfo {
    private String materialNumber;
    private String materialDescription;

    public MaterailInfo(String materialNumber, String materialDescription) {
        this.materialNumber = materialNumber;
        this.materialDescription = materialDescription;
    }

    // getter setter methods

}
```

**StyleInfo:**

```
class StyleInfo {
    private String StyleNumber;
    private String styleDescription;

    public StyleInfo(String styleNumber, String styleDescription) {
        StyleNumber = styleNumber;
        this.styleDescription = styleDescription;
    }

    // getter setter toString methods

}
```

**TEst12:**

```
public class TEst12 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<MaterailInfo> mList = new ArrayList<MaterailInfo>();
        mList.add(new MaterailInfo("a", "a-desc"));
        mList.add(new MaterailInfo("b", "b-desc"));
        mList.add(new MaterailInfo("c", "c-desc"));

        List<StyleInfo> sList = new ArrayList<StyleInfo>();
        sList.add(new StyleInfo("a", ""));
        sList.add(new StyleInfo("b", ""));
        sList.add(new StyleInfo("c", ""));

        for (MaterailInfo m : mList) {
            for (StyleInfo s : sList) {
                if (s.getStyleNumber().equals(m.getMaterialNumber())) {
                    s.setStyleDescription(m.getMaterialDescription());
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(sList);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think Java 8 probably has a very nice way to handle this using streams.

Comment: Thanks @Tim, but i am limited to java 6 :(

Comment: Could you use a `Map` instead of a `List` here?

Comment: Do you want improve complexity?

Comment: Yes, If there are no duplicates. Map is a better choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a `Map` instead of a `List` to store your data, you can get away with doing only a single loop:

```
Map<String, String> mMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
mMap.put("a", "a-desc");
mMap.put("b", "b-desc");
mMap.put("c", "c-desc");

Map<String, String> sMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
sMap.put("a", "");
sMap.put("b", "");
sMap.put("c", "");

for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : mMap.entrySet()) {
    sMap.put(entry.getKey(), mMap.get(entry.getKey());
}
```

This code will leave the style description empty if the style number does not match any known material number.

Comment: why did u exclude if statement ?

Comment: The `if` statement isn't necessary because the lookup process implicitly does this check.

Comment: i guess i could be done using one loop with List as well rather using Map. let me post solution

Answer (score 0):

If your numbers can't have duplicates, using a HashMap instead of classes can be a bit faster.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Map.Entry;


public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashMap<String, String> mList = new HashMap();
        HashMap<String, String> sList = new HashMap();
        mList.put("a", "a-desc");
        mList.put("b", "b-desc");
        mList.put("c", "c-desc");
        sList.put("a", "");
        sList.put("b", "");
        sList.put("c", "");

        Iterator entries = sList.entrySet().iterator();
        while (entries.hasNext()) {
            Entry entry = (Entry) entries.next();
            if (mList.containsKey(entry.getKey())) {
                sList.put((String) entry.getKey(), mList.get(entry.getKey()));
            }
        }

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : sList.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using one `for loop` like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < mList.size(); i++) {
   sList.get(i).setStyleDescription(mList.get(i).getMaterialDescription());  
}
```

Note: i am assuming you have balanced lists in term of size.